Given that the sum on one of the squares is 3 cents, and on another one 17 cents, find the total amount of money on both diagonals of the checkerboard
A number of coins are placed on each square of a standard 8x8 checkerboard such that the sums of every two squares having a common side differ by one cent. Given that the sum on one of the squares is 3 cents, and on another one 17 cents, find the total amount of money on both diagonals of the checkerboard.
Attribution:  V. Proizvolov

We observe that

 17 - 3 = 14 = (8 - 1) x 2, which is the number of orthogonal steps from one corner to the opposite corner

so the only way this works is if

 let's say 3 is on the bottom-left and 17 is on the top-right, then values must increase as you go towards the right or towards the top

You can prove this by noticing first that

 all the boundary values are absolutely forced

and iteratively that

 two diagonally-adjacent values differing by 2 will fix their mutual neighbour

Therefore the diagonals are

 3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17=80 and 10 x 8 = 80. So the answer is 160.


"all adjacent values differ by exactly 1" is given in the puzzle, is it not?  I think it's a stronger condition you mean to assert, such as that the values must increase by 1 between each pair of adjacent squares, from left to right and from top to bottom.

Ah yes, fixed it @JohnBollinger thanks
